# Using asp.net ajax client side framework on a bare-bones HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-ajax

I want to use the asp.net ajax client side framework on a bare-bones HTML page. Firstly, is it possible? If yes, then can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you use the asp.net ajax client side framework, it's no longer a bare-bones html page. Please elaborate one what you'd like to accomplish.

Comment: what i mean here is, i have a simple HTML page without any server-side framework and i want to use the asp.net ajax client side framework on this page. What are the steps i need to follow in order to find and load the necessary javascript files onto this HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to include MicrosoftAjax.js and start using it. For further reference you can check the following links:

- [Microsoft Ajax Client Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx)
- [Using Microsoft Ajax with PHP](http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/05/19/using-microsoft-ajax-in-php.aspx)
  In a word you need to include the file and start using the API. What exactly do you need from ASP.NET Ajax? Have you considered using jQuery instead? My experience tells that ASP.NET Ajax is suitable for ASP.NET only cases (web-forms, server controls, partial rendering etc) whereas jQuery is more close to the metal and works with all server platforms.

Comment: i have a user-control which calls a wcf service and plots the resultant data as a graph on the canvas tag. my requirement is to create a webservice which spits out the markup generated by this user-control so that anybody can use this user-control. i have created a service for it and the html page which is calling my webservice is able to render the markup but it fails to call the wcf service. As all these files are in the same solution so all the requests are within the same domain, so my guess was that the ajax client side framework is not loading up correctly.

Comment: This is a known limitation - cross domain ajax is not allowed in some browsers. As a workaround you can implement JSONP or have a local server proxy which will request the original WCF service.